# Failed to run React-Native on Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am getting this error after following an official guidelines of React Native here:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
I tried to open the simulator and run the command again but I am getting the same error.

````
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
/bin/sh: adb: command not found
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081```
````

Comment: You don’t have any emulator installed. You can install emulator in Android Studio or connect your android phone to your machine for testing.

Comment: please check your `adb` path is configured properly if emulator or android device already connected.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect an android device ( Activate developer mode ) or open an emulator from
AVD manager of Android studio

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following from terminal, inside the project folder

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{yourusername}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Then `npm run android`